# Docker failing to start rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, redis, resque

I'm trying to start my rails application using rails. It depends on redis, which seems to be working but when rails server starts it fails with `Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for [::1]:6379 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)`.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.6.1

RUN apt-get update -yqq && \
  apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
  nodejs \
  nano

COPY Gemfile* /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN bundle install
RUN gem install foreman
RUN gem install rake -v 12.3.2

COPY . /usr/src/app/

CMD [ "bin/rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0" ]
```

#### .docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:10.3-alpine'
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    env_file:
      - '.env'

  redis:
    image: 'redis'
    # volumes:
    #   - 'redis:/data'

  rails:
    depends_on:
      - 'postgres'
      - 'redis'
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
    env_file:
      - '.env'

volumes:
  redis:
  postgres:
```

#### log

```
rails_1     | => Booting Puma
rails_1     | => Rails 5.2.2.1 application starting in development
rails_1     | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
rails_1     | Exiting
rails_1     | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:1213:in `__connect_nonblock': Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for [::1]:6379 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb:1213:in `connect_nonblock'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:180:in `connect_addrinfo'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:220:in `block in connect'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:218:in `each'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:218:in `each_with_index'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:218:in `connect'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:296:in `connect'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:342:in `establish_connection'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:104:in `block in connect'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:299:in `with_reconnect'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:103:in `connect'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:372:in `ensure_connected'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:224:in `block in process'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:312:in `logging'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:223:in `process'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:123:in `call'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis.rb:1347:in `block in sadd'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis.rb:50:in `block in synchronize'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis.rb:50:in `synchronize'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.1.0/lib/redis.rb:1346:in `sadd'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-namespace-1.6.0/lib/redis/namespace.rb:442:in `call_with_namespace'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-namespace-1.6.0/lib/redis/namespace.rb:328:in `method_missing'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/resque-2.0.0/lib/resque/data_store.rb:65:in `method_missing'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/resque-scheduler-bbf4930c2802/lib/resque/scheduler/scheduling_extensions.rb:94:in `set_schedule'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/resque-scheduler-bbf4930c2802/lib/resque/scheduler/scheduling_extensions.rb:51:in `block in schedule='
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/resque-scheduler-bbf4930c2802/lib/resque/scheduler/scheduling_extensions.rb:50:in `each'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/resque-scheduler-bbf4930c2802/lib/resque/scheduler/scheduling_extensions.rb:50:in `schedule='
rails_1     |   from /usr/src/app/config/initializers/resque.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
rails_1     |   from /usr/src/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
rails_1     |   from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
rails_1     |   from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
rails_1     |   from config.ru:in `new'
rails_1     |   from config.ru:in `<main>'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
rails_1     |   from bin/rails:4:in `require'
rails_1     |   from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It appears to be one of 2 things. 

1. Redis could not run on the default port for some reason, and when rails tries to establish a connection to the specified port, it fails as it does not find a Redis instance there.

2. Is there another process running that is using port 6379?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for [::1]:6379 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)`

Your rails application is trying to connect to redis via localhost but the service is on a different container. Try connecting to `redis:6379` instead.